# Best approach to extend native JS Object

Tags: javascript, regex

Hei,

I'm trying to create my first lib in JS and the main purpose is extend the native RegExp object with some helpers, like sum, toDate, etc.

What would be the best approach to do so? Is there a design pattern to help with that?

How i'm doing:

```
void function() {
  'use strict';

   Object.assign(RegExp.prototype, {

     sum() {
     },

     toDate() {}

     ...
   });

}();
```

Thanks!

Comment: The best approach is to never extend native objects and methods. They cause performance troubles and can break other libraries.

Comment: Why they cause performance troubles?

Comment: agree with @FezVrasta. What you can do, though, is create a new class of objects which extend RegExp with the new ES6 class syntax. Something like `class MyExtendedRegExp extends RegExp { sum () {..}, toDate () { ... } }` and `let r = new MyExtendedRegExp('.*')` should do the trick. You won't be able to create instances of the new class using RegExp literals, though.

Comment: @FátimaAlves I remember a warning of Firefox talking about the need to convert the native code to JS when a native prototype get extended. I'm not sure if I remember it correctly or if it's still true tho.

Comment: If you want to know where the performance troubles come from, you need to understand the JS Interpreter. You'll find a nice writeup for chrome's V8 here: http://thibaultlaurens.github.io/javascript/2013/04/29/how-the-v8-engine-works/